# Ajax include script blocking page load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using Ajax Include Script(Dynamic Drive) to embed content cross-domain(CORS).

**Problem:**

There's ~2 sec blank screen when page with include script is clicked. Browser shows content only when entire page is rendered, including cross-domain content, which takes some while.

Is it possible to run that script after the page is loaded? I don't have both server permission so adding onLoad to body tag is not an option. 
I tried many scripts, no one did work. Everyone is giving out: ajaxinclude is not defined.

At this moment I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxinclude("http://domain")</script>
```

This made no difference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load(){
    ajaxinclude("http://domain");
  } window.onload = load();</script>
```

Comment: You will have to modify the ajaxinclude function so that it accepts callbacks. Since it uses XMLHTTP requests, you can check for the success state and fire the callback then.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling load immediately. . assign reference of load to window.onload instead of its returned value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load(){
    ajaxinclude("http://domain");
  } window.onload = load; // give function reference to onload

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now external content loads after page is loaded, but it's not loading into it's DIV, it looks like redirect now.